# Merging dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge, plyr

I have two dataframes. One is like the following

```
> head(df1)
  dropOffZip hour transition Day7
1      622    0     72  1
2      04745    0      1  1
3      05823    0      1  1
4      06490    0      1  2
5      06807    0      1  2
```

And the second one is like following :

```
head(df2)
  dropOffZip Day7 hour Median Count
1     622    1   0     60     1
2     622    2    8     60     1
3     622    3    8     60     1
4     622    7   12     60     1
```

Now I want to make `df3` by merging `df1` and `df2` based on common value for `dropOffZip`, `Day7` and `hour`. The issue is while all the combination of day, hour, dropOffZip are available in df1, it's not the case for df2. So, in the merged df3, I still want to have rows for those combinations missing in df1, but the corresponding value for `Median` and `Count` should be assigned `0`. Could anyone suggest how to achieve this merging?

The final `df3` should be like :

```
>head(df3)
  dropOffZip Day7 hour Median Count Transition
1     622     1    0    60      1      72
2     04745   1    0    0       0      1
```

Here the second row gives `Median = 0` and `Count = 0` because we don't have any column for `dropOffZip` `04745` in data frame `df2`

Comment: Please show what the new data should look like

Comment: Have you tried specifying `all=TRUE` in `merge`?

Comment: yep, `merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE)`

Comment: I think all = TRUE is giving unwanted rows with lots of NA values

Comment: Why don't you have rows for `05823`, `06490` and `06807` `dropOffZip`s in your desired output too? It doesn't make any sense, what's so special in `04745`? Also, when you can't merge you won't get zeroes as a result because zero has a meaning. Instead you will get `NA`s in your `Median` and `Count`. Anyhow, it seems like you need some thing like `df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("dropOffZip",  "Day7", "hour"), all.x = TRUE)`. If you want to assign zeroes to your `NA`s, just do `df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0` though I don't think it makes sense to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving all = TRUE in merge and remove the unwanted NA using complete.cases(df3). Else add a new column called median and assign it to NA. Just rbind it and remove the unwanted rows with NA using complete.cases.